# How to find out how much numbers are in array

Tags: c, arrays

EDIT : Ok,so answer was told by @Mischo5500. Thank you all,guys

How to find out how much numbers are in array except space? My program will find out length of array, until user input will be space and that is the problem. So if I have inserted "10 20 300", the length will be 2. I have expected 3,like three numbers,which were inserted.And I don't know,how much numbers will user type in. I have already tried strlen(p),it was the same thing. Can you help me? Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{
float p[1000];
scanf("%f",p);
int length=(sizeof(p)/sizeof(float));
printf("%d",length);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to print the elements of the array too or you just want length?

Comment: Your program only allows the user to enter one value. You need a loop if you want to enter more than one value.

Comment: Can you use C++ or must your solution be strictly in C?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, strictly in C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i tike it right (sorry if not), you want to calculate number of entered float values. It is easier for you to insert them in string format and convert them to float after processing, if you don't know number of arguments, that will be typed in. Here is how your code can look like for example, float numbers are in `val` variable, number of inserted values is in `length` variable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{
    char p[1000];
    float val[1000];
    int length = 0;
    char* itr;

    fgets(p, sizeof(p), stdin);

    itr = strtok(p, " ");
    while(itr != NULL)
    {
        val[length] = atof(itr);
        itr = strtok(NULL, " ");
        length++;
    }

    printf("%d",length);

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: If you want "length" of first element, just use strlen() on first token

```
itr = strtok(p, " \n");
if(itr)
{
    length = strlen(itr);
    val[length] = atof(itr);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can take in the user inputs in the form of command-line arguments which get passed in to the program as

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

That will give you the entire length of arguments. You would convert each of the arguments argv[i] to numbers.

Comment: Your solution, which is very clever, would give you the total **number** of strings entered on the command line.  The problem just wants the length of the first string occurring before the first space.  So you need to find the **length** (not `sizeof`) of `argv[1]`.  Note that `argv[0]` is the name of the C program.

Comment: The question says to find out the "length of array" of user inputs, not the length of the first input value. Please read the title of the question.

Comment: Here is what the question says: "My program will find out length of array, until user input will be space. So if I have inserted "10 20 300", the length will be 2."  Note carefully that the answer is **not** 3, which is what your code would attempt to give.

Comment: See Mischo5500's answer too. Can the original author of this question please clarify which answer he wants? Thanks

Comment: i would like to find out length of whole array except space. Maybe the question is how much numbers are in array